# Вид СПП по союзу когда

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "Когда взбираешься на гору, назад ни делай ни шагу" союз "когда" будет относиться к союзам условия (я думаю, что возможна замена союзом "если") или всё же к временным союзам? Или, например, в таком предложении: "Когда на небе солнце, звёзд не видно". Просто от вида союза будет зависеть и вид придаточного. И как вообще поступать в подобных случаях? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Это интересный вопрос.**

1. Вид СПП не всегда можно определить только **по союзу**, так как к одному виду может относиться **несколько союзов**. Поэтому главное – это определение **смысловых отношений между частями предложения** (такие отношения называются общим грамматическим значением для данного вида СПП).
2. Сравним это грамматическое значение для  разных СПП (времени и условия).

**СПП с придаточным времени**: временное соотношение двух ситуаций. В этих СПП  основным союзом является КОГДА , а союз ЕСЛИ даже не упоминается.

**СПП с придаточным условия**: Придаточная часть выражает условие, при котором может или могла бы осуществиться ситуация главной части.

Эти условия бывают **трех видов**: (1) ирреальное (условие не осуществилось), (2) потенциальное  (может осуществиться) и (3) реализованное.  Примеры: ***Если бы** не было дождя, мы пошли бы гулять. **Если** не будет дождя, мы пойдем гулять.*

Третий вид – это уже **несобственно-условное предложение**, оно часто описывает реальные, но **повторяющиеся** события . Именно эти предложения могут сближаться по значению с предложениями **временной обусловленности**: ***Когда (если)** заходил, приносил детям подарки.*

3. Решение задачи

***Когда (если)** взбираешься на гору, назад не делай ни шагу. **Когда (если)** на небе солнце, звёзд не видно.*

Получается, что по всем признакам эти предложения относятся к **СПП условия** и имеют частное значение **временной обусловленности**, то есть описывают повторяющиеся, но реальные события.

4. Сравним: ***Когда** взошло солнце,  звезд уже не было видно.* ЭТО СПП времени со значение временного соотношения двух ситуаций.